# Удалить столбцы матрицы, последний элемент которых положителен

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{system("chcp 1251"); system("cls");
int n;
cout << "Введите n = ";
cin >> n;
int **a = new int*[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    a[i] = new int[n];
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Матрица: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
     for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
     {
      a[i][j]=rand()%200-100;
      cout.width(4);
      cout << a[i][j] << " ";
     } 
     cout << endl;   
    }

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     if(a[n-1][i] <= 0) 
     {
//здесь нужно удалить столбцы
     }  


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вы нашли положительный элемент то создавайте новую матрицу с количеством столбцов меньше чем один и делайте копию старой без этого столбца. В идеале стоит заполнять матрицу определенными констатами(в вашем случае стоит взять INT_MAX) Так же стоит считать количество столбцов при переопределении значений, когда вы пройдете все столбцы в матрице необходимо скопировать в новую динамическую матрицу те значения которые вы не трогали,и освободить старую матрицу. Так же не забудьте освободить свою новую матрицу.P.S Если вы хотите что бы вам написали код то бы покажите что вы старались разобраться

Comment: "...покажите что вы старались разобраться..." - полностью поддерживаю предыдущего оратора. Без этого кода не будет. Кстати, джентльмены находят, что предварительное прочтение рекомендаций, как задать вопрос на форуме, существенно сокращает время ожидания ответа.

Comment: Что значит "удалить столбцы"? Как "удалить"? Сформировать новую матрицу меньшего размера? Или что-то другое?

Answer (score 1):

Для массива `a[n][m]` первый индекс описывает строки, а столбцы описывает второй индекс, т.е.   `m`    это количество столбцов. Так как по заданию нужно удалять столбцы, то:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if(a[i][n - 1] > 0) // последный элемент i_той строки
    {
        delete[]a[i];
        a[i] = 0;
    }
```

Но это может привести к крушению, если только вы все это не инкапсилируете с правильным использованием(поскольку массив будет содержать нулевые указатели). Распечатать можно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(a[i]) {
        cout.width(4);
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Но все же лучше создать новый массив указателей и удалять старый:

```
int sz = n;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if(a[i][n - 1] > 0)
    {
        delete[]a[i];
        a[i] = 0;
        --sz; //чтобы узнать количество неудаленных
    }
if (sz != n) {
    int** temp = new int*[sz];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (a[i]) {
            temp[j] = a[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    delete []a;
    a = temp;
}
```

теперь наш указатель(массив) можно безопасно использовать(нулевых указателей нет, но количество строк может быть меньше)

```
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout.width(4);
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
}
```